# How do I set the parental rating on a video?

Tags: windows-7, video

I can view the properties  (right click, properties, details) of a video file and it has a field for **parental** rating.

How can I add a rating to the file (the field is blank)?

There is the problem that if I can add a rating, someone else may be able to change it to circumvent parental controls on a video player.  This isn't of concern to me at this time.

Edit: The file types are both .avi and .mpg.

Edit 2: I own the file and have 'full control'.

Edit 3: I should clarify, the field on the details tab is empty and read-only. I can't change it. Perhaps there is a setting elsewhere that changes the field to read/write.

Edit 4: I confirmed that converting the video to a .wmv file type does allow me to change the parental rating as well as many other properties. None of the properties on the Details tab can be changed for a .mpg file. This is not a practical option for me.

Comment: You should just be able to edit the field. Click to the right of the field name and you should be able to edit it, unless you don't have security privileges to edit the meta data.

Comment: @Rhys: Clicking on the rating field where I would expect an edit box simply highlights the row.  There is no edit box, no (right click) context menu, nothing.  Perhaps there is a registry key to enable editing?  An internet search did not uncover any solution, only several others with questions just like mine.

Comment: What is the file type? .avi/.mpg/.mov/... ?

Comment: It looks like you can edit the row but I am not sure of what information it is expecting.

Comment: Just out of curiousity what is the purpose of what you are trying to accomplish? Is this for some sort of indexing/catologing where this kind of metadata is important for you to have or do you simply want to prevent people (your children maybe?) from accessing the video? No judgement at all if thats the case but there are definitely options for password protecting/locking down the file so only certain people can open it

Comment: @JesseCarter: This is just for my own cataloging so that when I select a movie, I can make sure the rating is appropriate for my audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Windows mechanism for setting Parental rating is the following :

1. In Windows Explorer, right-click the file and choose properties
2. In Details tab, under Content, click in the edit field to the right of "Parental rating"
3. Type or modify the Parental rating
4. Press OK

However, as far as I could see, this only works for some file-types.
For me it worked for .wmv files but not for .avi.

Another equivalent method is via the library of Windows Media Player, as is described in detail in the answer by @Serge or in the article
[How to Edit a Video Description](http://www.ehow.com/how_7803894_edit-video-description.html).
However, this method doesn't work any better for .avi files than the previous one.

Conclusion: The Windows method of using a file's Properties in order to set Parental rating
only works for Microsoft-sponsored file-types.

Just to also remark that these details of the video can be easily lost when transferring
the file to a disk that is not formatted as NTFS (most external disks are formatted
as FAT32 which does not support these details).
This is therefore a very fragile container for video metadata, easily lost,
not to be depended upon for the long-term.

Comment: The question is for "parental rating", not "star rating".

Comment: I rewrote the answer. Don't be too hasty with undervoting.

Comment: I should clarify, the field on the details tab is empty and read-only. I can't change it. Perhaps there is a setting elsewhere that changes the field to read/write.

Comment: Which type of file is it?

Comment: Never mind - I saw your update. I'm sorry to say that this doesn't work for either .avi or .mpg. IMHO your options are: (1) Convert your videos to .wmv for which this works (2) Use a video catalog product that supports Parental rating and which doesn't use Microsoft's Properties/Details mechanism.

Comment: Can you suggest products with this capability?

Comment: See [Best Free DVD Collection Software](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-dvd-collection-software.htm). Few of them however do Parental rating. [Griffith](http://griffith.cc/index.php?option=com_frontpage%20&Itemid=1) seems to have customizable fields so you can add it.

Comment: Why would MS allow editing of properties on some file types (.wmv) but not others (.mpg, .avi)? The prop is already there, why disable edit?

Comment: Thanks for the list of software. These appear to keep the information in their own database. I was hoping to attach it to the file itself (in the NTFS database?) so that several computers can access it without installing said software on all my computers and finding a way to link that database to the software.

Comment: Microsoft will only do so for its own file-types, which is one of the reasons that these file-properties are almost never used by anyone except Microsoft. The only alternative I can think of is to incorporate this info in the file-name, or to create sub-folders for each rating (which will also mean that you could set differing access permissions on folders per user-account).

Answer (score 0):

To expand and add a source to @harrymc's answer:

The property "parental controls" is indeed only available for some types, but those types are not necessarily just the Microsoft sponsored ones. The are any files that have a bunch of metadata properties that are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862(v=vs.85).aspx).

Unless you are thinking about writing a new file container that wraps around a .avi or .mpg file, and then writing a codec so that Media Player (or any other player for that matter) can read it, you are just out of luck.

The list of file properties that are available for any file can be found [here](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880&page=1).